# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list' retriving a int from a int list

Tags: python

I am getting the following error:

```
PrimaryDiagonalSum+=v
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'

I am just trying to retrieve a int from a list that was converted to int by mapping.
What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/python

import sys


arraySize = int(raw_input().strip())
array = []
for i in xrange(arraySize):
    temp = map(int,raw_input().strip().split(' '))
    array.append(temp)
counterPrimaryDiagonal=0
counterSecondaryDiagonal=arraySize-1
PrimaryDiagonalSum=0
SecondaryDiagonalSum=0
for i in range(arraySize-1):
    v=array[counterPrimaryDiagonal]
    v2=array[counterSecondaryDiagonal]
    PrimaryDiagonalSum+=v
    SecondaryDiagonalSum+=v2
    counterPrimaryDiagonal=counterPrimaryDiagonal+arraySize+1
    counterSecondaryDiagonal=counterSecondaryDiagonal+arraySize-1
print(abs(PrimaryDiagonalSum-SecondaryDiagonalSum))
```

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with `pd += v`? As the error states, pd is an int and v is a list.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but are you using totally meaningless variable names on purpose only to confuse the reader ? Meaningful variables names make for readable code, and it's much easier to reason about readable code and spot logical error.

Comment: how come v is a list if I am extracting just one item of array a using a[cp]?

Comment: take a look at line v2=a[cs] it returns same error

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers this is hacker rank. part of the names come to them and the correction is automatic, no human read need. I can change it for the question.

Comment: Can you share the problem details(title, url etc)? I think I have solved this earlier.

Comment: Given a square matrix of size , calculate the absolute difference between the sums of its diagonals.
input is like 1st line matriz size, other lines are matrix lines of ints separated by spaces

Answer (score 0):

Problem statement:

> Given a square matrix of size , calculate the absolute difference
>   between the sums of its diagonals. input is like 1st line matriz size,
>   other lines are matrix lines of ints separated by spaces

Based on the above statement it can be achieved like the following:

```
import sys
arraySize = int(raw_input().strip())
array = []
for i in range(arraySize):
    temp = list(map(int,raw_input().strip().split(' ')))
    array.append(temp)
PrimaryDiagonalSum=0
SecondaryDiagonalSum=0
for i in range(arraySize):
    for j in range(arraySize):
        if i==j:
            PrimaryDiagonalSum+=array[i][j]
        if (arraySize-1)-i==j:    
            SecondaryDiagonalSum+=array[i][j]
print(abs(PrimaryDiagonalSum-SecondaryDiagonalSum))
```

Sample Input:

```
4
1 2 3 8
4 5 6 6
7 8 9 3
5 6 9 8
```

Sample Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one single iteration (i.e. no need for *j*)

```
abs(sum(array[i][i]-array[i][-i-1] for i in range(len(array))))
```